# Flask-SQLAlchemy ON DELETE SET DEFAULT

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, sql-delete, cascade

I have two simple tables in Postgre DB:
User and Role with relation many to one with following code behind:

```
    class User(db.Model):

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
        created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
        username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
        password = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=False, nullable=False)
        email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=True)
        active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
        role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='SET DEFAULT'), server_default = '1', nullable = False)

        role = db.relationship('Role', backref = db.backref('users', lazy = True), passive_deletes = True)
```

And

```
class Role(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

ON DELETE SET DEFAULT constraint on DB acts correctly however SA is forcing NULL update to role_id BEFORE deletion take place, rising integrity error.

```
2018-09-25 14:08:54,922 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE "user" SET role_id=%(role_id)s WHERE "user".id = %(user_id)s
2018-09-25 14:08:54,922 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'role_id': None, 'user_id': 2}
```

I've tried cascade options and passive_deletes with no effect. What should be the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
passive_deletes = 'all'
```

does the job, however order of relationship declaration is important so
removing **role** declaration in *User* and creating opposite **users** relation in *Role* did the job. Now SA relays fully on DB setup.

```
users = db.relationship('User', backref = db.backref('role', lazy = True), passive_deletes = "all")
```

in Role class.